# Mobile safari: iframe missing cookies

Tags: cookies, mobile-safari

I have a web app located on domain A which contains an iframe on domain B. The request to the src on domain B has some Set-Cookie headers. If i load this web app with Safari, or chrome, I can see the cookies set from the iframe request in developer tools. However, if i visit the same page on the iOS simulator (iOS 12), the cookies are not set and I get auth errors (due to missing cookies). I haven't had any luck finding anything online about this behaviour so I have no idea how to work around it. I feel like I must be missing something because this seems like it would be a giant missing feature.

Unfortunately, i haven't had time to setup a simple reproduction for this issue.

Any kind of advice would help.

Comment: So turns out this issue was specific to iOS simulator but also exists in iOS PWA implementation (regardless of simulator or real device)

Answer (score 4):

The issue is with Safari iOS do not allow setting cookies from domain B, unless you "explicitly visit" B. Workaround is to visit the iframe domain and set blank cookie there, then bounce back to original A domain. Afterwards your "Set-Cookie" directives or whatever you use to set cookies will be allowed by iOS.

Check out this solution and discussion (also includes reproduction setup):
https://gist.github.com/iansltx/18caf551baaa60b79206